# Adding CSS Gradient as Background Image Programatically

Tags: javascript, css

Why is it that I can define a rule in CSS like this

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
}
```

and everything works perfectly fine, but when I do this in JS

```
var red = document.getElementById('red');
red.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
red.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);';
```

It only seems to work in IE, and not Chrome or Firefox?

**How do you get the same behavior when the styles need to be set in JavaScript?**

```js
var red = document.getElementById('red');
red.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
red.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);';
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 5px black;
  font-size: 2em;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01) 1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  CSS Styling
</div>
<div id="red">
  Programmatic Styling
</div>
```

I'm currently running with the following versions:

- Firefox 45.0.1
- Chrome 49.0.2623.110
- IE 11.0.9600.18230

Comment: d'oh, I even tried that at first but for some reason it didn't work (at first).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply remove the `;` from the end of the backgroundImage value on Javascript, which currently is:
`linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);`

So, in the end, you'll have:

```js
var red = document.getElementById('red');
red.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
red.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%)';
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01) 1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<h1>
CSS Styling
</h1>
<div class="red">
</div>
<h1>
Programmatic Styling
</h1>
<div id="red">
</div>
```

Comment: -facepalm- Such a rookie mistake on my part. The fact that it was working in IE had me puzzled. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing, I made the exact same mistake and had to find this answer for me to realize…

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `setAttribute` instead:

**Edit:** Oh, or just remove the semicolon in the string as one commentator suggested:

```
var red = document.getElementById('red');
red.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
red.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%)';
```

Original answer content (ignore or use at will):

```js
var red = document.getElementById('red');
red.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:red;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%)');
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 5px black;
  font-size: 2em;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01) 1%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  CSS Styling
</div>
<div id="red">
  Programmatic Styling
</div>
```