# Setting linear graidents in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my current code, I'm trying to set the background of my site to a rainbow gradient however this code isn't working, however I know its being called as the alert goes off on the page? How would I go about fixing this?

```
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var day = date.getDay();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var month = date.getMonth();

if (month == 4) {
    document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor = `linear-gradient(red, yellow, green)`;
    alert("test");
}
```

Comment: Use `style.backgroundImage `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding CSS Gradient as Background Image Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524156/adding-css-gradient-as-background-image-programatically)

Comment: From MDN: creates an image consisting of a progressive transition between two or more colors along a straight line. Its result is an object of the <gradient> data type, which is a special kind of <image>

Answer (score 0):

Use `el.style.background` not `backgroundColor`.

See examples here: [MDN linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient())

```js
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var day = date.getDay();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var month = date.getMonth();

if (month == 4) {
    document.getElementById("container").style.background = `linear-gradient(red, yellow, green)`;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```